# Win32 FindFirstFile Non-terminating Wildcard Expansion

Tags: c++, winapi

The win32 API for `FindFirstFile` says that it allows a file name to end with a wildcard character, but says nothing about having a wildcard that is not the last character. Does Win32 support this or will I have to process every file in a directory to find those with a desired extension?

For example, is the following valid?

```
WIN32_FIND_DATA outputData;
HANDLE hFind = FindFirstFile("some-dir/*.txt", &outputData);
```

Comment: The documentation says "The directory or path, and the file name, which can include wildcard characters, for example, an asterisk (*) or a question mark (?)."  Nothing about the wildcard having to appear at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation does not say that wildcards need to appear at the end of the string. And there is no such requirement. Your file name of

```
"some-dir/*.txt"
```

is valid and will match every file in `some-dir` with `.txt` extension.